# RxJs Obesrver wrapped around websocket only fires on one subscriber

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am wrapping a websocket in an RxJS observable like so:

```
this.wsObserver = Observable.create(observer=>{
          this.websocket.onmessage = (evt) => {
              console.info("ws.onmessage: " + evt);
              observer.next(evt);
          };
      });
```

This works, but if I add multiple subscribers, only one fires (the last one added):

```
this.wsObserver.subscribe((result) => {
        console.info("! result: " + result);
      });
      this.wsObserver.subscribe((result) => {
        console.info("!2 result: " + result);
      });
```

Only `!2 result:` occurs.

Why?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrite the `onmessage` handler in your creation handler so only the last subscriber (which is the last to set the `onmessage` value) is called.

What you could do is:

```
var var messageSubject = new Subject();
this.websocket.onmessage = (evt => messageSubject.next(evt));
```

and then

```
messageSubject.subscribe(...)
```

will work for as many subscribers as you want

Comment: Interesting, it does fix the problem.  But why?  Isn't the Observer.create call in the original code only called once, and then subscribed to twice?

Comment: The create function gets a handler function that's invoked for every new subscriber

Comment: Thanks -- that is helpful going forward as well!